# Server Side d3 - Encoding SVG as a Base64 Image

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to encode a D3 chart as a base64 image for use in HTML emails

So far I have:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var jsdom = require('jsdom');

app.get('/chart', function (request, response) {
    try {
        jsdom.env(
            "<html><body><svg id=\"svg\"></svg></body></html>",
            ['http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js'],
            function (err, window) {
                var svg = window.d3.select("svg")
                    .attr("width", 100)
                    .attr("height", 100);

                svg.append("rect")
                    .attr("x", 10)
                    .attr("y", 10)
                    .attr("width", 80)
                    .attr("height", 80)
                    .style("fill", "orange");

                var encoded = ...; // How do I now encode this?

                response.send({
                    "html": window.d3.select("body").html(),
                    "encoded": encoded
                });
            }
        );
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
});

// Run Server
var port = process.env.PORT || 8305;
var server = app.listen(port, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    console.log('App listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

This outputs the SVG html which is useful however I would also like a second response field `encoded` which should contain something like below that I can use in my HTML email:

```
"encoded": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEU...etc"
```

How do I encode this SVG? I would like to avoid any file writing if possible and go straight from SVG to encoded image. Also, I'm aware you can use SVGs in emails but I would much rather it be in an encoded image format. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Full solution which builds a d3 chart using NodeJS and converts it to an encoded PNG without using file storage (neccessary for most cloud hosting)

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();

let jsdom = require('jsdom');
let Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;
let svg2png = require('svg2png');

app.post('/chart', function (request, response) {
    try {
        jsdom.env(
            "<svg id=\"svg\"></svg>",
            ['http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js'],
            function (err, window) {
                let svg = window.d3.select("svg")
                    .attr("width", 100)
                    .attr("height", 100)
                    .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");

                svg.append("rect")
                    .attr("x", 10)
                    .attr("y", 10)
                    .attr("width", 80)
                    .attr("height", 80)
                    .style("fill", "orange");

                let data = "data:image/png;base64,";
                let svgString = svg[0][0].outerHTML;
                let buffer = new Buffer("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>" + svgString);
                let promise = svg2png(buffer, {width: 300, height: 400}); // This options block is optional but height and width should be specified on the SVG HTML otherwise
                promise.then(buffer => {
                    let dataURI = data + buffer.toString('base64');
                    response.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                    response.send({
                        "html": svgString,
                        "encoded": dataURI
                    });
                });
            }
        );
    } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
    }
});

// Run Server
let port = process.env.PORT || 8305;
let server = app.listen(port, function () {
    let host = server.address().address || 'localhost';
    console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

The `encoded` field in the response can be used in a HTML email using:

```
<img src="{encoded-value}"/>
```

e.g

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA..."/>
```

Comment: It works but you have to use jsdom 9.12 or before since jsdom.env is deprecated now (2020)

Comment: This is the one

Answer (score 8):

Set the `"xmlns"` attribute at root `<svg>` node to `"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` at `<svg>` node within `document` or with `.attr()`.

The [`data URI`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397) scheme consists of

```
data:[<media type>][;base64],<data>
```

Since we know that the `<media type>` will be `image/svg+xml` and that we want `base64` representation of resulting data, we can define a variable to which we will concatenate `base64` representation of `<svg>`.

```
let data = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,";
```

Then we get the `.outerHTML` of `<svg>` element

```
// optionally preceded by `XML` declaration `<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>`
let svgString = svg[0][0].outerHTML;
```

Call [`btoa()`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#dom-btoa) with `svgString` as parameter

> The `btoa(data`) method must throw an "[InvalidCharacterError](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#invalidcharactererror)"
> [DOMException](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-DOMException) if *data* contains any character whose code point is
> greater than U+00FF. Otherwise, the user agent must convert *data* to
> a sequence of octets whose nth octet is the eight-bit representation
> of the code point of the *n* th character of *data*, and then must
> apply the base64 algorithm to that sequence of octets, and return the
> result. [[RFC4648]](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/references.html#refsRFC4648)

```
let base64 = window.btoa(svgString);
// concatenate `data` and `base64`
let dataURI = data + base64;

response.send({
                "html": window.d3.select("body").html(),
                "encoded": dataURI
             });
```

```js
let svg = window.d3.select("svg")
  .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 100);

svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 10)
  .attr("y", 10)
  .attr("width", 80)
  .attr("height", 80)
  .style("fill", "orange");

let data = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,";
let svgString = svg[0][0].outerHTML;
let base64 = window.btoa(svgString);
let dataURI = data + base64;

console.log(dataURI);

document.querySelector("iframe").src = dataURI;
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
<iframe></iframe>
```

Comment: This is great thanks, I don't think I'll be able to use the script tag in a HTML email though unfortunately. Also what's the benefit of using an iframe over an img?

Comment: @Ed0906 The `<iframe>` was included at stacksnippets solely to demonstrate that the generated `data URI` represents `<svg>` image

Answer (score 1):

In order to send it as a png image, you would first have to rasterize the svg, which is the actual problem. This has been answered in several places, but [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845488/svg-to-png-convertion-with-imagemagick-in-node-js) contains a number of good solutions. You should probably use imagemagick for the conversion. Since you want to avoid writing to an intermediate file, that answer suggests you can pipe the svg contents to the converter's stdin.

The received buffer could probably be [directly encoded to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182315/how-to-do-base64-encoding-in-node-js).

Comment: Thanks, would it make things much different if I allowed writing to the file system?

Comment: In that case you would not pipe svg to the converter, but instead save the svg to a file, and then pass the filename to the converter. So, not too different. Look at the imagemagick documentation for some hints too.